# Perform fetch every time tab is focused in TabNavigator [ReactNavigation]

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation's TabNavigator. In the first tab, a user is able to enter a call record and submit it to our server. In the second tab, that data and other records are fetched from the server and displayed in a list. The problem arises when a user enters a record and switches to the second tab. The second tab has already performed componentDidMount and will not pull the new record, even when setting `lazy: true` in the options. Is there any way to accomplish this functionality? I explicitly need to perform an API call to fetch the most recent data every time the tab is switched to. If not, I already know a less elegant workaround using redux, so please no suggestions to just use redux.

```
CallRecords:
{
    screen: TabNavigator(
    {
        EnterCallRecord: {
            screen: EnterCallRecordContainer,
        },
        ViewCallRecords: {
            screen: ViewCallRecordsContainer,
        }
    },
    {
        lazy: true
    })
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this really great component [react-navigation-is-focused-hoc](https://github.com/pmachowski/react-navigation-is-focused-hoc) :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17880868)

Comment: Yeah, sure, but in this particular it is not a simple answer, it's a component that does the job ;)

Comment: This may be brief, but is now more relevant, as react-navigation has discontinued 'lazy'.